# Windows 8 Installation couldn't find drives

Tags: windows-8, installation, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows on Ubuntu using a bootable Windows USB stick. Basically I want to multi boot with Ubuntu and Windows 8.
However, on the "Where do you want to install Windows?" installation windows, it doesn't show any available drives.

[image: No visible drives in the windows 8 installation - Here's the Image]

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the drive shows in BIOS, there is a decent possibility Windows 8 does not recognize the SATA controller.  Download the driver from the manufactures website and copy the driver onto the USB stick.  Then load the driver with the `Load Driver` link on the dialog of your screenshot.